# Execute external application with PHP

Tags: php

I have a linux command line that I need to execute witin either PHP or Javascript (PHP preferred.)

The command is `keygen AB3554C1D1971DB7 \pc_code 365`

However, I would like to substitute the `\pc_code` with a string like $pccode where user enters the generated PC Code.  This is for a legit project, but having a problem with creators of the program giving me assitance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that this program is poorly written and outputs its information to stderr instead of stdout.  Or it could be that it is failing and (properly) printing the error message to stderr.  In either case, shell_exec wouldn't capture stderr.  However, **you should be able to capture stderr by adding "`2>&1`" to the end of your command**, i.e.:

```
$result = shell_exec('keygen AB3554C1D1971DB7 \pc_code 365 2>&1');
echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars($result).'</pre>';
```

**Edit**: For continuity's sake, what fixed the problem was something mentioned in a comment to another answer below:

> Maybe it doesn't like the bare backslash? you could try "`\\pc_code`"

Comment: Okay...tried that...still not working.  This is the error

sh: keygen: command not found

HELP!?!?

Comment: Okay...the way the code is written, it should be ./keygen...but now it says permission denied.  How can I change this?  I use GoDaddy.com

Comment: KIP:  It works, I added the additional \ to \pc_code and it works...at least it generates a code...anyway...thanks for the help.  Unless you can provide me with a quick script to reload a page onSubmit with form generated information added.?  Just a thought.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [shell_exec()](https://www.php.net/shell_exec):

```
$cmd = sprintf("keygen AB3554C1D1971DB7 %s 365", 
               escapeshellarg($pccode));
$result = shell_exec($cmd);
```

Whenever you execute external commands you have to be extremely careful to avoid command injection. You can prevent this using [escapeshellarg()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php).

Comment: If *$pccode* is relatively simple, like only a string of numbers, then it's best to check that there are really only numbers in there. No telling what *keygen* does with the string behind the scenes. Also, check for a specific maximum length.

Comment: Okay, I tried it, however, it didn't work.  However, here is the script:
$cmd = sprintf("keygen AB3554C1D1971DB7 \pc_code 365");
$result = shell_exec($cmd);
?>
<div align="center">Activation Code: <? echo $result; ?>

Please let me know what I did wrong.

Comment: Did you use `%s` and `escapeshellarg()` in place of `\pc_code`?

Comment: No, I substituted %s with \pc_code and removed the escapeshellarg() completely.  And when I did <? echo $result; ?> it returns NOTHING!  Please help.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't like the bare backslash?  you could try "`\\pc_code`"

Comment: Can you confirm that shell_exec works for you at all?  it could be that you don't have permission to run it for some reason.  try running the sample code from the shell_exec page: $output = shell_exec('ls -lart'); echo "<pre>$output</pre>";

Comment: Kip, here's what I got from the ls code.

total 652
-rw----r--  1 webmasterbark inetuser 550379 Jul 23 05:49 keygen
-rw----r--  1 webmasterbark inetuser  94208 Jul 23 06:34 KeyGen.exe
drwx---r-x 22 webmasterbark inetuser   4096 Jul 24 03:44 ..
-rw----r--  1 webmasterbark inetuser    659 Jul 25 21:11 index.php
drwx---r-x  2 webmasterbark inetuser   4096 Jul 25 21:11 .

Hope this helps

Comment: @Aaron that does tell me that you don't have any problem running shell_exec. So the problem *must* be in the command you are running. does it work when you run it directly from a linux shell? are you sure that it uses a **back**slash? (if so that's pretty uncommon.) you should maybe also try this to ensure that you're not just getting non-printing characters as result: `<?php echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars($result).'</pre>' ?>`

Comment: Nothing.  Here's the "Help" file information:

for Linux 
./keygen MyProductCode \pc_code
and 
./keygen MyProductCode \pc_code 365

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [exec](https://www.php.net/function.exec)

Answer (score 0):

Executing a Linux command isn't really possible from JavaScript (nor should it be).  Assuming you're referring to JavaScript that is run on a client's web browser, there would be no security model that would keep people safe from malicious command line access.  PHP is a different story.